# What is the best practice to retrieve all customers from Stripe API into one list

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

When calling `Stripe::Customer.all(:limit => 100)` there is a limit of 100 per call. We have a lot more customers than that, and I would like to get them all at once. Am I missing something, or is this only possible by writing a naive loop that checks on the `has_more` attribute and then makes a new call until `has_more = false`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are right, you must write a naive loop with a cursor [per the stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#list_charges):

> ### starting_after
>
> *optional*
>
> A cursor for use in pagination. `starting_after` is an object ID that defines your place in the list. For instance, if you make a list request and receive 100 objects, ending with `obj_foo`, your subsequent call can include `starting_after=obj_foo` in order to fetch the next page of the list.

Here's one in case anyone needs a quick copy-paste.

```
  def self.all_stripe_customers
    starting_after = nil
    customers = []
    loop do
      results = Stripe::Customer.list(limit: 100, starting_after: starting_after)
      break if results.data.length == 0
      customers = customers + results.data
      starting_after = results.data.last.id  
    end
    return customers
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, was helpful! I did make one important change though, this code (almost) always makes one more query than it has to. Instead it should check `results.has_more` in the while condition.

Comment: one addition - you probably want to rescue from `Stripe::RateLimitError` and retry after waiting an appropriate amount of time

Comment: should be `loop do`

Comment: This answer is no longer the best solution. The Stripe API now offers an "auto" pagination feature which makes this much easier: https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=ruby

Answer (score 13):

Probably a little late to the game here, but here's a yielding version of Doug's answer which loops through every customer, yielding them to a block:

```ruby
def each_stripe_customer
  starting_after = nil
  loop do
    customers = Stripe::Customer.list(limit: 100, starting_after: starting_after)
    break if customers.data.length == 0
    customers.each do |customer|
      yield customer
    end
    starting_after = customers.data.last.id  
  end
end
```

You can use this as follows:

```
each_stripe_customer do |customer|
  puts customer.id
end
```

This abstracts away the fetching of customers from however you actually want to use them.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to docs "auto pagination", https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto

```
customers = Stripe::Customer.list({limit: 10})
customers.auto_paging_each do |customer|
  # Do something with customer
end
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to go to Stripe Dashboard and export all customers to a CSV file.
Maybe not the best approach since you will not get the updates, but it's an option.

Answer (score 1):

Since Google points here and the question only mentions ruby in the tags, if someone needs the python code, here is @Doug's answer "**translated**" **to** the **python** stripe api, then generalized to get ***any*** stripe object:

```
import stripe #https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=python
# must loop e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393300/what-is-the-best-practice-to-retrieve-all-customers-from-stripe-api-into-one-lis
def get_all_stripe_objects(stripe_listable):
    objects = []
    get_more = True
    starting_after = None
    while get_more:
        #stripe.Customer implements ListableAPIResource(APIResource):
        resp = stripe_listable.list(limit=100,starting_after=starting_after)
        objects.extend(resp['data'])
        get_more = resp['has_more']
        if len(resp['data'])>0:
            starting_after = resp['data'][-1]['id']
    return objects
all_stripe_customers = get_all_stripe_objects(stripe.Customer)
all_stripe_products  = get_all_stripe_objects(stripe.Product)
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to keep a local copy of customer data. so you get the data from Stripe API only once & use that local copy instead of asking that same data again-again.

For syncing changes,
There are two main approaches you might use to make sure your database has the latest state:

- In your code that makes API calls to Stripe, be sure you're also updating your local copy, or
- Use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to listen for [events related to your customers (e.g., `customer.created`, `customer.deleted` etc)](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types). By doing this, you can be sure your local database always matches up with Stripe – even if you change your customer's plan via the dashboard, your webhook endpoint will receive the update.

The primary benefit to storing this data locally apart from getting around API limitations, is speed.

You will want to make sure you're storing the [customer ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) in your database so that you can match up the Stripe customer with your local user.

Hope it helps

Comment: This may be good advice, but it doesn't answer the question - and you have no reason to think that the OP isn't *already* doing what you advise. Even if you have a local copy of the data, it's quite possible that you'll need to pull everything directly out of Stripe from time to time either to fix up bugs or gaps in recording your local copy, or for auditing purposes. Plus anyone who *hasn't* yet taken this advice needs an answer to the question that was asked in order to set up their local copy to start working from. This answer can't possibly help anybody on its own.