# stripe how to set limit for the expandable objects

Tags: stripe-payments

In stripe, we have the option to expand some of the child object when the property has the expandable option. And the expandable property is not shown by default. For example in customer object, we have the sources list which is not shown by default. But we need to expand it when retrieving the customer by adding the expand parameter - "sources" as below.

```
var customer = this.stripeService.getCustomer(stripeCustomerId(), List.of("sources", "default_source.card"));
```

Now since sources is a  list it by defaults shows only 10 cards. But I wanted to limit that to more number say 20. How can we do this on the expandable property?

Answer (score 1):

I Still did not find a way to set the limit but we can fetch all the items without the default limit of 10 using the following code. The key is ***autoPagingIterable*** that brings all the data without paging

```
var customer = this.stripeService.getCustomer(stripeCustomerId(), List.of("sources", "default_source.card"));
    if(customer.getSources().getHasMore()){
        List<PaymentSource> paymentSources = new ArrayList<>();
        customer.getSources().autoPagingIterable().forEach(paymentSource -> {
            paymentSources.add(paymentSource);
        });
        customer.getSources().setData(paymentSources);
        customer.getSources().setHasMore(false);
        customer.getSources().setUrl(null);
    }
```

Reference -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/64173387/12752873

Answer (score 0):

The `autoPagingIterable` is the right approach but it's best to be used on the correct API endpoint.

From Stripe's [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-08-27):

> The sources property on Customers is no longer included by default. You can expand the list but for performance reasons we recommended against doing so unless needed.

If you want to get a customer’s sources you should call the separate [endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list).